# Why is the following code an endless loop? (for-loop)

Tags: c

This chunk of code is in a exercise from the book named C programming-A Modern Approach.

```
for(i=10;i>=1;i/=2)
{
    printf("%d", i++);
}
```

Edited:

The first output should be 10 and it should increase by 1 for the next step in the loop.But when i run this code all i get is 1 and it never ceases to print 1.

Please help me understand this code.

Comment: `The first output should be 5` - wrong.

Comment: Try it, see the output, think about it, see how a `for` loop is executed and then, if you can't understand something, ask here.

Comment: Definitely i am missing something here. Would you please point it out. Thank you.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code

Comment: the code loops infinitely when it reaches 1 so you're probably just losing the first few numbers in your console. change the terminating condition to see the first few numbers (it should start by printing _10_): `for (i = 10; i > 1; i /= 2)`

Comment: I thought once to flag this post as "not welcome to our community" because of a possible hate speech to passionate learners and debuggers.

Comment: This code will produce neither 5 nor 1 on the first run.

Comment: @KirilKirov yes you are right. First output is 10. Thanx

Comment: @pb2q You are spot on. On the output console for some reason i was unable to see the numbers 10, 5 etc. even when i scrolled up. Tested the code on the debugger turns out that you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code says

```
for( start with 10 ; as long as it is greater or equals 1 ; divide i by 2){
    Print i;
    add 1 to i
}
```

So:

```
start with 10:
print 10;
10 + 1 = 11
11 / 2 = 5,5 = 5 because it's int
print 5
5 + 1 = 6
6 / 2 = 3
print 3
3 + 1 = 4
4 / 2 = 2
print 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 / 2 = 1
print 1
1 + 1 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
print 1
1 + 1 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
.... and it will continue forever and ever
```

Execution order of for loops:

```
for([init];[1];[3]){
    [2]
}
```

Of course the order [1],[2],[3] is repeated until [1] is not true anymore

Comment: At first i = 10. Then it is compared whether i greater than/equal 1. Then i becomes i/2=5. It should print 5 and make i increase by 1. So i will become 6 and the next step of the loop will start. Am i correct?

Comment: @riznomdemha - what you're missing is the order of evaluation of the statements in a `for` loop.

Comment: I added the execution order of a for-loop. thanks @Kiril Kirov

Comment: Accepting it as an answer for your clear explanation. Turns out i was wrong about the first output and unfortunately the output console was showing only 1's.Thanx and if you don't mind would you please help me understand why i am getting so many down votes for this question.

Comment: The down votes are probably for the poorly phrased heading (which i edited). It lacked to describe the actual problem you had. Maybe it also got down votes for being trivial. If this sample is from a book, the book surely describes how for-loops work. If it doesn't: Get a different book! ;-) Me... i don't mind answering trivia...

Comment: The book is OK but i wasn't thinking carefully to understand... anyway thank you for explaining. :D

Answer (score 1):

The code is use less. It will produce output as `10 5 3 2 1 1 1 1 . . .` infinite times `1`, because when `i` becomes 1 by dividing by 2, value is again incremented in `printf` statement ir. `i++` and becomes 2.

So the code results in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

i starts as 10, it will run as long as i > or = 1, each iteration i decreases by half (i/2).

The print is going to print the value of i, then increment it by one. SO

```
Iteration 1:
  10  (i+1 = 11)
Iteration 2:
  5   (i/2 = 5 + 1 = 6)
Iteration 3:
  3   (i/2 = 3 + 1 = 4)
Iteration 4:
  2   (i/2 = 2 + 1 = 3)
Iteration 5:
  1   (i/2 = 1 + 1 = 2)
...
Iteration N:
  1   (i/2 = 1 + 1 = 2)
```

Every iteration after that will be 1. which is why you see 1 printed forever, I think you can see why.

Answer (score 0):

If your output starts at 1, then your test condition in the loop is written as `i=1`, and not `i>=1`. Fix your test condition, and you will see the loop execute properly.

Speaking of which, that should be as follows: as `i=10` at the start of the loop, that will be your output. The `i++` then increments `i` to 11, post usage in the print statement.

When the code reaches the bottom of the loop, it will then execute the loop step adjustment (`i/=2`). This means 11\2=new i value. That will be 5. Then the code will test the new value of `i` and proceed through the loop again, and it will repeat these steps until `i < 1`.

As at `i`=1 step, you will then have `1+1` = 2 and `2/2` = 1, the loop will never cease once started (as the test `i>=1` will always be true). Are you sure your output starts at 1, or does it quickly go from 10 to 1 and then you just get a lot of ones?